# Managing classes in Python programming

Tags: python, python-3.x

## UPDATE

> Tells me that `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'storlek'`

## My class

```
class Hanterare:
    def __init__(self, storlek):
        self.storlek =storlek
```

## My functions

```
def fråga_storlek():
    try:
        Hanterare().storlek =int(input('Choose size'))
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong try again!!")
        fråga_storlek()
```

And I want to use the value, the user has chosen and call them into my other functions for example:

```
def getNewBoard():
    board = []
    for i in range(fråga_storlek()):
        board.append([' '] * fråga_storlek())
```

Comment: Take some time and read a Python OOP tutorial. There are a bunch of them on the intewebs, just ask Google about it. For example: [this one](https://python.swaroopch.com/oop.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, to create a field in a class, you should declare it in a function called `__init__(self)`. Like so:

```
class BoardHandler:
    def __init__(self, Q):
        self.Q = Q
```

You can also take input upon creation instead of having it as a parameter, like so:

```
class BoardHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Q = int(input("What size would you prefer?"))
```

You don't want to use:

```
class BoardHandler:
    self.Q = 5 #some number
```

unless you want the board size to be the same across *all* `BoardHandler`s.

Then you can access it in other methods of the class by just using `self.Q`.
To use it outside the class, here's how:

```
b_size = int(input("What size?"))
bh = BoardHandler(b_size)

print("The board size is: " + str(bh.Q))
```

Comment: No problem, I rolled it back

Comment: it tells me that `self is not defined` @MLavrentyev

Comment: Where are you calling that? `self` is only for internal use inside the class definition. If you create a BoardHandler object named `bh`, you can use `bh.Q` to access that BoardHandler's size

Comment: Awesome, how I have fixed everything, The only current problem I have is that when I run  the program it goes into an endless loop with questioning me `what zise would you prefer?` What have I done wrong? @MLavrentyev

Comment: If you only initialize once, it should only ask once. Can you post what you're doing?

Comment: Updated! @MLavrentyev

Comment: @Pythongirl make sure you define `storlek`. You need to either have it as a parameter (see example 1 above) or if you want user input, like example 2 above

Comment: Yeah but when I add "storlek" into my parameter `def __init__(self, storlek):` it gives me `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'storlek' `

Comment: That means that when you create a BoardHandler object you need to provide that as a parameter. Try `bh = BoardHandler(5)`. Then you can replace 5 with the value the user inputted

Comment: Yeah, but if the value of the user inputted changes every run, how do I replace that?

Comment: and you mean `self.bh = BoardHandler(5)` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless I'm missing a notation, `Q` is a terrible name. Variable and method names should be in lowercase, and describe the purpose of the variable. `board_width` would be a much better name.
2. Having a method with the same name as a class member is confusing. Since you're asking for the board size, I'd rename the method to something like `ask_board_size`.
3. After taking the above into consideration, the problem solves itself:

---

```
class BoardHandler(self, board_size):
self.board_size = board_size

   def ask_board_size(self):
    try:
        self.board_size = int(input("Choose size please"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong try again!")
        ask_board_size()
```

And is that constructor a new notation? It should probably use `__init__`:

```
class BoardHandler:
    def __init__(self, board_size):
        self.board_size = board_size
    ...
```

Comment: And I would acces the board size trough `Boardhandler().board_size` ?

Comment: @Pythongirl Well, you would create a Boardhandler, then call `ask_board_size` on it, then get the board_size member of it. With the code you posted in the comment, you never call `ask...` on it, and never give the constructor a value, so `board_size` wouldn't contain a value (and not passing a value to a constructor that expects one is an error).

Comment: @Pythongirl If you have an `ask... ` method, it also doesn't make much sense to pass the width in through the constructor, since you won't know what width to use until you ask. I suppose you could use it as a default value though.

Comment: How would I then call on board_size?

Comment: only by `self.board_size`

Comment: @Pythongirl From within the class, yes, that's how you'd access it. From outside the class, you'd get the `board_size` member of the instance of the class you created.

Comment: So, just to get it clear, I call from outside the chat, only by using `ask_board_size`?

Comment: @Pythongirl No. You would create an instance of the class: `handler = Boardhandler()`, then use it to ask for input: `handler.ask_board_size()`, then get the size: `handler.board_size`. I agree with the commenter on your question. You should probably review OOP to make sure you understand the purpose and use of classes.

Comment: @Pythongirl Note though, that whether or not using a class here is appropriate is debatable. It might make more sense to just have a `ask_board_size` function outside of the class, then store its result somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I am currently trying it your way but the error `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'board_size`